# Get picklist values in apex in the order they were entered

Tags: apex, picklist

I want to get the picklist values of a picklist field in Apex.

I use the `someFieldResult.getPicklistValues();` function and that works fine. This gives me all the picklist values, in alphabetic order (e.g. Alpha, Beta, Gamma).

However, I want to have those values in the order they were entered (e.g. Gamma, Alpha, Beta). How to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [DescribeFieldResult.getPickListValues](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeFieldResult_getPicklistValues) method returns the values in their currently defined order. If you sort then after you have entered them by e.g. checking the:

> Sort values alphabetically, not in the order entered. Values will be
>   displayed alphabetically everywhere.

checkbox then that sorted order will be the only one available to you from the platform.

But you can go back and manually reorder the values. I suggest you do that via the "Reorder" button displayed for the "Picklist Values" of a picklist field.

Comment: Now that I debug the list, yes, this seems to be the case. I was confused because the order is again messed up when I show the List of options in Visualforce: they always show in alphabetic order. Is there something I can do about that?

Comment: Oh well, nevermind. I used a map, and that never works for sorting. Now I use the original List and all is fine! Thanks.